# Wrong back button behavior when using setOnItemSelectedListener when using it on BottomNavigationView android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

By default in Android, when using the `BottomNavigationView`, navigation by pressing on item looks like this:

A -> B -> C

Back button: C -> A

But when using `setOnItemSelectedListener`, the navigation breaks and when you click on the back button it looks completely different:

A -> B -> C

Back button: C -> B -> A

How can I fix this and make it so that when the back button is clicked, the navigation always leads to the first (startDestination) item?

My code:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
    when(it.itemId) {
        R.id.homeFragment -> { navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment) }
        R.id.favoriteFragment -> { navController.navigate(R.id.favoriteFragment) }
        R.id.profileFragment -> { navController.navigate(R.id.profileFragment) }
    }
    true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
menu.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.homeFragment -> {
                val graph = navController.graph
                graph.startDestination = R.id.homeFragment
                navController.graph = graph
            }
    }
}
```

> But that's the best  `menu.setupWithNavController(navController)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That is the code you looking for:

```
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            navController.popBackStack(item.itemId, inclusive = false)
            true
        }
```

This will delete all bottom navigation item's backtrack.

Comment: This will not go back to homeFragment